# Is there a general term for the individual resources in a (modern) library?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

A modern library would have not only books but audio/video tapes, magazines, journals, etc.

Of course I could use a non-library-specific term like *resource* or even just *item* (maybe prepending each with the word *library*), but I'm wondering if there's a library industry piece of terminology for the individual 'things' being cataloged?

Comment: A quick search shows that at least some (university) libraries use the term "resources", so as you suggest, "library resources" can be used.

Answer (score 1):

**Item** is consistently used by the USA's [Library of Congress](https://www.loc.gov/about/general-information/). Consider

> Today's Library of Congress is an unparalleled world resource. The collection of more than 164 million **items** includes more than 38.6 million cataloged books and other print materials in 470 languages; more than 70 million manuscripts; the largest rare book collection in North America; and the world's largest collection of legal materials, films, maps, sheet music and sound recordings.

[...]

> *Year 2016 at a Glance*
>
> Circulated more than 997,000 **items** for use inside and outside the Library
>
> Preserved more than 10.5 million **items** from the Library's collections
>
> Recorded a total of 164,403,119 **items** in the collections:
>
> 24,189,688 cataloged books in the Library of Congress classification system
>
> 14,660,079 **items** in the nonclassified print collections, including books in large type and raised characters, incunabula (books printed before 1501), monographs and serials, bound newspapers, pamphlets, technical reports, and other printed material
> 125,553,352 **items** in the nonclassified (special) collections, including:
> 3,670,573 audio materials, (discs, tapes, talking books, other recorded formats)
> 70,685,319 manuscripts
> 5,581,756 maps
> 17,153,167 microforms
> 1,809,351 moving images
> 8,189,340 items of sheet music
> 15,071,355 visual materials including:
> 14,290,385 photographs
> 107,825 posters
> 673,145 prints and drawings
> 3,392,491 other **items**, (including machine-readable **items**)

Comment: "Items" is the single best choice. Libraries used to use "volumes," but that word doesn't capture holdings that are not books sufficiently. One of the problems with "titles" is that its meaning may not be clear when dealing with items that share a single name, such as five physical copies of a single print edition of a book or magazine. "Resources" is probably a little too broad, as a specialist librarian or archivist could be considered a resource.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **published work** or **publication**; with preference leaning toward "published work" or even just "work"

Example Sentence: *The library holds over 10,000 published works.*

Example Sentence: *The library has the complete works of Ray Bradbury.*

> **[Work](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/work)**
>
> 3. A thing or things done or made; the result of an action.
>
>    3.1 A literary or musical composition or other piece of art.
>
>    3.2 The artistic production of a particular author, composer, or artist, regarded collectively.

---

> **[Publication](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/publication)**
>
> 1. The preparation and issuing of a book, journal, or piece of music for public sale.
>
>    1.1 The action of making something generally known.
>
>    1.2 A book or journal issued for public sale.

Comment: The concrete usage 1.2 is not said to include CDs etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But the primary definition is said to include music.

Comment: No; the primary definition is 'the preparation and issuing of a book, journal, or piece of music for public sale' not 'a book, journal, or piece of music for public sale'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I guess I don't understand what point you are trying to make? Are you saying a CD is not a publication?

Comment: I'm saying that your reference doesn't license this usage. (I'd never call a CD a 'publication' myself, though they go through the publication process. Just like I'd never call someone who prepares a scheme of work a 'schemer'.)

Comment: @Skooba, with regard to "publications," what about papyri? Or manuscripts and private letters? In some cases, not all of the items held by a library have been published.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the term *title*.

> **title** *noun*
> 1.2 A book, magazine, or newspaper considered as a publication.
> ‘Two Fox Movietone News clips of the cast and crew arriving and working in Japan and trailers for House of Bamboo and the rest of the recent spate of Fox film noir titles fill out this DVD.’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/title)

As the example in the definition shows, titles are not restricted to paper publications.

However, although actual libraries allow searches for *titles*, they tend to use the generic term *item* to refer to the resources, as the following example shows.

The [Cairns library](http://www.cairns.qld.gov.au/library/my-library/libguides) uses the generic term *item* (emphasis, mine).

> [03 - Library Guide - How To - Reserve An **Item**](http://www.cairns.qld.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0006/53709/03-Library-Guide-How-To-Reserve-An-Item.pdf)
>
> You can reserve up to fifteen (15) **items** that are out on loan or at another library by using our catalogue either in the library or at home.

These items aren't restricted to books. The catalog search boasts of "over 160,000 **items** made up of the following:"

- Books - fiction, non-fiction, large print, languages other than English for adults, youth and children
- Magazines
- DVDs
- Music CDs
- Kits
- Talking books, in CD, MP3, and Playaway formats

Comment: I prefer the more 'physical' item over title. I think a title may consist of several items. For a lending library, the challenge is to keep track of physical objects. Titles may come in several formats, such as hard cover, paperback, large print editions and audio books.